# can updated my text form to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to updated text via php ,i can query the actual text store in my sql and show in the input box ,when i try to update nothing was change ,
i put the variable in echo to see if it work and i can read the new text on my confirmation pages but still nothing change on my database ,i try my updated directly on mysql and it work
here is a my code

```
enter code here
<?php
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['thisID'])) {
    $id = $_POST['thisID'];
 $name = 'names';
$textes = $_POST['textes'];
// See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE library SET name='$name',textes='$textes'WHERE   id='$id");                                                  
echo ''.$id.' New text is online, cliquer <a href="inventory_list.php">ici</a>.';

 exit();

 }
 ?>
 and my form
  <form action="text_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform"      method="post">
    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
     <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Title</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="64" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"  />
    </label></td>
    </tr>    
    </form>
</td>
    </tr>
    <?php echo ''.$targetID.' ';?>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Text</td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="textes" id="textes" cols="64" rows="5"><?php echo $textes; ?>       </textarea>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td ><label>
      <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="btnsaveedit" value="Save Changes" />
    </label>&nbsp;
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in your query. Also, what if your text contains a single quote?

Comment: this is not a final file i know about security issue i twist so much the code I feel like I'm about to go crazy...just kiddin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE library SET name='$name',textes='$textes'WHERE   id='$id");
```

insted of

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE library SET name='$name', textes='$textes' WHERE   id=$id ");

Comment: my white space was create when a post it ,its late and this my second time in 1 years i post it but thank for your answer

Comment: find it i forgot a single quote after $id

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you have to ensure $targetID variable have a value and then `</form>` tag have to close at end of all form fields.

```
$sql = "UPDATE library SET name='".$name."',textes='".$textes."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer yes all the form was close and you can see above i put an echo $targetID and i see it when i load the pages

Comment: find it i forgot a single quote after $id